# Jquery scrollTop moving not scrolling to target element

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I have a parent `div#content-area-steps`,with `overflow-y: scroll`, which contains the form elements. when i scroll to bottom of div and if element is missing from center of form the scroll reaches at top of the parent div but not targeting the parent element.

```
if(app.car.price<=0 || app.car.price>1000000000 || app.car.price==""){
        $('#price_label').css('color','red');
        $('#content-area-steps').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#price_label").offset().top
        }, 1000);

        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(app.car.price<=0 || app.car.price>1000000000 || app.car.price==""){
          $('#price_label').css('color','red');
          var top = $(this).position().top
          $('#content-area-steps').animate({
                 scrollTop: top
           }, 1000);
           return false;
 }
```